# How to write regex that checks if word starts with letter and contain {3,6} numbers and letters?

Tags: regex

I need to write regex that check following words: must start with a letter, may contain {3,16} numbers and\or letters.

I tried the following regex `\b[A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z0-9]*{3,16}\b`, but I get error.
What is wrong?

Comment: What is the exact error? Also please post the code where you are using this.

Comment: do you mean 6 (per the title) or 16 (per the text) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting the error because of the `*`. Remove it to get a valid regex:

```
\b[A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z0-9]{3,16}\b
```

However, this regex isn't quite what you want, which is:

```
\b[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]{2,15}\b
```

You need `{2,15}` (and not `{3,16}`) because the first character counts for one of the `{3,16}`

Comment: will this be valid if I add round brackets like this \b([A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z0-9]){3,16}\b?

Comment: @theateist: No, because then you'll require 3 to 16 repetitions of `[A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z0-9]`. By the way, "atheist" is spelled with an "h" :)

Comment: @TimPietzcker - Alternately he's a thespian who's missing an "r" ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that that you second character class has both `*` and `{3,16}` which means the `{3,16}` has nothing to quantify.  Additional you state that input string must start with just one letter but `+` means `1..many`.  I imagine you want:

```
\b                  // boundary
[A-Za-z]            // single character
[A-Za-z0-9]{2,15}   // A further 2-15 alpha numerics
\b                  // boundary
```

Answer (score 0):

Some sample Python code:

```
subject = """
This is som3 s@mpl3 text.

One possible sixteen letter word is abstractednesses. 2012 is not
a word as it does not contain any alphabetic charat3rs.

Unfortunately conventionalizations contains 20 characters.
"""

import re
words = re.compile('((?<=\s)[A-Za-z]\w{2,15})\W', re.M)
res = words.findall(subject)

# res is:
# ['This', 'som3', 'text', 'possible', 'sixteen', 'letter', 'word', 
#  'abstractednesses', 'word', 'does', 'contain', 'alphabetic', 
#  'charat3rs', 'Unfortunately', 'contains', 'characters']
```